# Comparing three Scala lists in Play Framework templates

Tags: scala, list, playframework

I'm trying to filter three lists of objects and output them in a loop, I use PlayFramework and i got Java running in the backend,  i only use Scala templates in my front end.

Let's assume the following:
I got 3 lists now: `AList`, `BList`, `CList`
List A and C don't have anything in common, but list B is the linking List in the middle, who acts as a connection. List C contains objects with two attributes: `idA` and `idC`. Now i want to receive all objects from `AList` and if it's ID exist in `BList` i want to display additional information coming from `CList`. I don't really have a clue how to approach this in scala. I read some threads about zipping lists together and came up with an approach like this:

```
@listCheckA = @{
    AList.map(a => (a,  BList.map(_.idA).contains(a.idA)))
}
@listCheckC = @{
    CList.map(c => (c, BList.map(_.idC).contains(c.idC)))
}
@listLinked = @{
    listCheckA.zip(listCheckC).map( ??? )
}
```

Afterwards i want to output the objects with a `for` loop.
If this might be a legit approach, what should i do at the listLinked to check my conditions?

Sorry if this question might sound dumb, I hardly used Scala before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it `C` or `B` that has an `idA` and an `idC`?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Thank you so much for your help again, i decided to create a new thread on this one - it's the same topic though. 
`B` objects contain both `idA` & `idC`. and `C` objects only contain `idC`. The `BList` only acts as an linking list. An object `b` is only used to determine which `C` object belongs to which `A` object.  The approach is really complicated but it was a predefined DB i'm working with, and i had to create a way to connect those tables/lists. The objects in `BList`are created manually.

Comment: Can't you do the join with your DB management system?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the DB I'm receiving my data from was originally created for a different application and i can't change the schema. I guess this is bad practice but these are the requirements. Is there no possible approach in Scala without killing performance completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this looks a lot like a many-to-may link table, which you should be able to handle using your DB library, something like

```
SELECT a.*, c.* FROM TableA as a, TableB as b, TableC as c WHERE a.idA = b.idA AND c.idC = b.idC`
```

If you really need to do this using scala (as I said in your previous thread, logic should not be in templates, but rather in your controller), you can do it as a for comprehension:

```
@for {
  a <- AList
  b <- BList if b.aid == a.aid
  c <- CList if c.cid == b.cid
} {
  // ... do whatever you want with a and b and c here ...
}
```

This is the same as three `for` loops inside one another, except that the `if` statements will do what it says (filter elements which satisfy the predicate).

You will find it difficult to do this more efficiently, unless you use a SQL statement as above to query directly in your DB.

Comment: This definitely makes sense and thank you for providing the sql solution. I want to try both solutions and see if the scala loop has an acceptable performance for this amount of data (probably not, three `for` loops inside each other doesn't sound like the best performance). 
Somehow the syntax in your example doesn't work for me. It says "Enumerator expected in the 'for' statement". Sorry the solution is probably obvious if someone is familiar with scala ... I'm feeling pretty dumb. Thank you for your patience though.